# A recursive equivalent to an iterative algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Code2, due to user BLUEPIXY, should represent a recursive algorithm equivalent to Code1. However, I am not completely sure that the Code2 is indeed recursive: is it ok to have a condition like this?

```
if(n>0){
            func();
            times(--n, func);
        }
```

Shouldn't you have a well-defined base case? Please, could you clarify?

---

Code1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printValue();

int main (){
   int n = 100;
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<n; i+=1)
          printValue();
}


void printValue(){
     static unsigned int y = 0;
     printf("y = %d", y);
     y+=1;
}
```

---

Code2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printValue(void);
void times(int n, void (*func)(void)){
    if(n>0){
        func();
        times(--n, func);
    }
}

int main (void){
    int n = 100;
    times(n, printValue);
    return 0;
}

void printValue(void){
    static unsigned int y = 0;
    printf("y = %d\n", y);
    y+=1;
}
```

Comment: Code looks fine, the recursion looks fine

Comment: What do you mean `a well define base case`? have you tried running both solutions to convince yourself the output is the same?

Comment: @John3136 I see that the output is the same, but I'm not entirely sure that code2 is a recursive algorithm. Could you explain why it is recursive?

Comment: @MooingDuck Could you just explain to me why it is really recursive, please? And also what is Nathan Tuggy talking about in his answer?

Comment: @mathlearner: A function that calls itself is obviously recursive.  And the `times` function calls the `times` function so....

Comment: @MooingDuck And is it ok to have if(n>0) instead of, say, "if (n=0) stop"? Also, do you know if there is a more straightforward way to convert Code1 into a recursive algorithm?

Comment: @mathlearner: Yes, that's OK. Not sure what I was looking at, but I completely missed the `times` call in Code2, hence my incorrect answer.

Comment: @mathlearner It's fine to have `if (n > 0)...`, the `times` function is void so when `n` drops below 1 nothing happens and that copy of the function terminates, returning to the invoker, which terminates, etc., etc.

Comment: @mathlearner: If it calls itself, it's recursive.  Period.  Always.  Doesn't matter what the rest of the code is.  That condition should be equivalent.

Comment: Side note: `--n` modifies `n` but the modified value is never used. `n-1` would be better. (Most compilers will do that anyway, since it's an obvious optimization, but the mutation of `n` is a distraction for human readers.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say code 1 is like that (I just created a new function that does the iteration, nothing else)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printValue();
int times(int n, void (*func)(void)) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        func();
}
int main (){
   int n = 100;
   int i;
   times(n, printValue);
}

void printValue(){
    static unsigned int y = 0;
    printf("y = %d", y);
    y+=1;
}
```

Here, times function calls printValue n times. But in your recursive example, it calls printValue, and calls times with n-1.

So for the cases:

Base case: `times(0)` should return

Iteration: `times(n)` should call `printValue` once, then call `times(n-1)`.

Comment: Op said `However, I am not completely sure that the Code2 is indeed recursive` and I offered a base / iteration case for code2. I also simplified code1 a little to emphasise that `times` function is recursive in code2, not code1.